# how to Remove `<option>` inside `<select>` by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my source:

```
<select>
    <option>option1</option>
    <option>option2</option>
    <option>option3</option>
</select>
```

I want delete one option:

```
<select>
    <option>option1</option>
    <option>option2</option>
</select>
```

How to do it With jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: `Dhaval Marthak `i'm sorry , but i searched before take this question and not find it!!!

Comment: you searched but did not find anything? i don't believe you

Answer (score 3):

To remove the option with value: `"option1"`:

```
$("#selectBox option[value='option1']").remove();
```

You will have to set values in your options, though:

```
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
```

Adding value properties also has the benefit that you can change the displayed value, while sending something the code understands back to the server:

```
<option value="option1">Mercedes</option>
<option value="option2">Volvo</option>
<option value="option3">Volkswagen</option>
```

The server will still receive `option1`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

For removing the last element simply do:

```
jQuery("select option:last").remove();
```

Of course you can change the selector to whatever you want, it must only point to one or multiple option elements.

Comment: I want to delete the second one then?

Comment: Then use jQuery("select option:nth-child(2)").remove()

Comment: If you need to remove the second how is it important how many options there are?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a specific option with index then you must use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) or `:eq` and [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
$('select option:eq(2)').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using simple JavaScript with your given example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oList = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0] ;
    var oOption = oList.options[2]; // to select the third childelement
    oList.removeChild(oOption); // to remove the childelement
</script>
```

This removes the third entry of the first select in the DOM. It would be a good idea to give your select an id like this:

```
<select id="sel"> ... </select>
```

This way you can select the element like this:

```
var oList = document.getElementById("sel") ;
```

---

Or with using jQuery use

```
$("#sel option:eq(2)").remove();
```

to remove the third item again.

Answer (score 0):

You should get this option by a selector...for example using an id, and then use the romove() function. For example:

```
<select>
  <option id="a">a</option>
  <option>b</option>
</select>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#a").remove();
```